# Project 'app' could not be found in workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, angular7, ionic4, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to establish chat (instant messaging capability) for my ionic4 application, I am trying to implement aws-amplify to achieve this(AppSync). When I run `$amplify serve` it gives below error. Not sure what's going on here, I tried to rename the app folder but it didn't work.. Any help in this matter is much appreciated, thank you..

```
Project 'app' could not be found in workspace.
[ng] Error: Project 'app' could not be found in workspace.
```

I have followed instructions from [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-a-serverless-real-time-chat-application-with-aws-appsync/) and [this](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-chat-starter-angular/tree/master/src)